# indexing a java matrix

Tags: java, indexing, matrix

I wanted to know if it's possible to have multiple columns of a matrix indexed to speed up sorting.   In MySQL you are able to have indexes on multiple columns which makes finding elements in the table faster, but I don't know if that's possible in a standard java matrix.  For example, my data is a 3-column matrix that has an id, first name, and last name, and then many entries on this table.  Right now I can say something like mat[5] and get the entry for the individual with the id of 5, but I also want to be able to search entries by the last name column.  How can I do this most efficiently in Java?

Answer (score 3):

If it's Java, you can always set up a hash table that associates last names to an array of matrix row indices, such that the people on those rows have that last name.

Or you can have a multi-level hash table, such that you can do `m[index.get(lastName).get(firstName)]`.

Also, if you want to iterate over names in lexicographic order, you can replace the hash table with a `TreeMap`.

Example:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Object[][] m = new Object[][]{
            {1, "Smith", "John"},
            {2, "Stone", "Jack"},
            {3, "Stein", "Robert"},
            {4, "Stone", "Bob"}
        };

        //index.get(lastName) will return a map between
        //first names and matrix row indices. 
        //index.get(lastName).get(firstName) returns the index
        //in the matrix of the row pertaining to person (lastName, firstName)
        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> index = 
            new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>>();

        //create index
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
            Object[]o = m[i];
            String last = o[1].toString();
            String first = o[2].toString();
            TreeMap<String,Integer> index2 = index.get(last);
            if (index2==null){
                index2=new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
                index.put(last, index2);
            }
            index2.put(first, i);
        }

        System.out.print("Smith, John -> ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m[index.get("Smith").get("John")]));

        System.out.print("Stone -> ");
        System.out.println(index.get("Stone"));

        System.out.print("Full index: ");
        System.out.println(index); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Smith, John -> [1, Smith, John]
Stone -> {Bob=3, Jack=1}
Full index: {Smith={John=0}, Stein={Robert=2}, Stone={Bob=3, Jack=1}}
```

In the example I gave, it's not enough to map last names to row indices, because you could plausibly have two persons with the same last name. I did however make the assumption that you won't have two people with the exact same name. Otherwise, you would need something like `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>`, in order to be able to find everyone with a given (last name, first name).
If you want to search by ID, you just need to create a second index, mapping IDs to row indices, which could be a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.

For this small example, there isn't much to gain from having the indices, as they probably take up more space than the matrix itself, but it probably pays off if your records are large.

Comment: hey sorry I'm not fully understanding how you would implement your suggestion.  If I have an array, and each slot points to a hash, and each of the keys in those hashes point to other hashes, how is that going to let me search by last names?  Say the entries are `1 - Smith, John`,`2 - Stone, Jack`,`3 - Stein, Robert`.  Can you show me how I would be able to search for the second entry both by its id (2) and its last name (Stone) using your code?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want more than one way to access a Java data structure, you are going to have to create additional, "parallel" structures.

For example, you can have your "main table" -- whether it's an array or a list or whatever -- that is sorted or keyed by name. Then you would create a second table sorted by, say, customer number, and each entry in that table could hold an index into the first table, or another copy of the handle of an object. Then you could have a third table sorted by birth date, whose entries also point to the first table, etc.

For example:

```
class Customer
{
  public String name;
  public int customerNumber;
  public int shoeSize;
  ... whatever ...
}
class byName implements Comparator<Customer>
{
  public int compareTo(Customer c1, Customer c2)
  {
    return c1.name.compareTo(c2.name);
  }
}
class byShoeSize implements Comparator<Customer>
{
  public int compareTo(Customer c1, Customer c2)
  {
    return c1.shoeSize-c2.shoeSize;
  }
}

... elsewhere ...
Customer[] nameOrder=new Customer[100];
nameOrder[0]=new Customer("Fred Smith", 10001, 9);
nameOrder[1]=new Customer("Mary Jones", 10002, 7);
... etc, however we get the list initialized ...
Arrays.sort(nameOrder, byName);

Customer[] shoeSizeOrder=new Customer[100];
for (int n=0;n<customerList.length;++n)
  byNumber[n]=customerList[n];
Arrays.sort(shoeSizeOrder, byShoeSize);
```

(Usual disclaimer: Untested code off the top of my head. Please excuse any syntax errors. Error checking omitted and other oversimplifications to give the idea. Etc.)

After this, you'll have one list sorted by name and another list sorted by shoe size. You could then scan each list in order, binary search to find particular values, etc.

Of course nothing says all the lists must be arrays. They could be hash tables, array lists, or any other structure that is either ordered or has a key/value mapping.

Note that this is not two copies of the same data. There is only one set of objects. We just have two HANDLES for each object, one in each list.